# A map of connected CW complex is a homotopy equivalence if it induces isomorphism on $\pi_1$ and the homotopy fiber is acyclic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is taken from excercise 4.3.16 from Hatcher: A map $f:X\longrightarrow Y$  of  connected CW complexes is a homotopy equivalence if it induces isomorphism on $\pi_1$ and its homotopy fiber $F_f$ has $\tilde{H}_*(F_f;\mathbb{Z})=0$.

By the setup, I believe we want to use Whitehead's theorem by showing $f$ induces isomorphisms on higher homotopy groups; A previous exercise with similar setup goes to show that if a lift of $f$ to the universal cover, $\tilde{f}:\tilde{X}\longrightarrow \tilde{Y}$ induces isomorphisms on the homology, then by using Hurewicz we may conclude the homotopy equivalence. However, I am not sure how does the homotopy fiber give us information about the covering spaces in this case. Any help on this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think basically the way this goes is that the homotopy fiber is simply connected and then try the LES of a fibration. For example, if $H_2(E_f,\mathbb Z)=0$, then $\pi_2(E_f)=0$, and so you can conclude that that $f$ is an isomorphism on $\pi_2$, and so on so forth.

Comment: Do not confuse Hatcher's $E_f$ and $F_f$ (it is the latter which appears in 4.3.16 and will generally not be homotopy equivalent to $X$). The hint for the question is that you should show that $F_f$ is simply connected, from which most of the problem follows easily.

Comment: I did misread $F_f$ for $E_f$ there! Thanks for the hint and I will edit the original problem.

Comment: I'll expand on my hint above. I'm not exactly sure of everything that Hatcher covers, so maybe this won't be very useful to you. $F_f$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex, so to show that it is contractible, it will suffice to show that it is simply connected and acyclic. It is acyclic by assumption, and given this assumption, for it to be simply-connected it is enough that $\pi_1$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have already solved this particular problem and I'll post the solutions when I find some time!